# Angular ngrx store reducer syntax problems

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

im working on angular project using ngrx store and i have the following reducer (old syntax) that works fine :

```
export function MyReducer(state = initState, action: Action): UserState {

  switch (action.type) {

    case UserActionsTypes.UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS:

      let updatedUser: USerDTO = (<USerActions>action).payload;
      let lstcurrentUsers = [...state.users];
      //update current user in list of users inside the store
      lstcurrentUsers = lstcurrentUsers.map(u => (u.id == updatedUser.id) ? updatedUser : u);

      return {
        ...state, dataState: USerStateEnum.LOADED, users: lstcurrentUsers, currentUSer: (<EnvelopeActions>action).payload
      }
      
      //...
```

now im working on a new syntax and this is my reducer :

```
export const MyReducer = createReducer(
    initState,

    on(UpdateUserActionSuccess, (state, { user }) => (
        {
            ...state, dataState: UserStateEnum.LOADED, currentUser: user, users: state.users.concat(user)
        }
    )),
    //...
```

my question is how i can add lines of code to manipulate state before returning it inside the `on()` method of my `createReducer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer function is just a callback function, so you can do any work you'd like inside of it:

```js
export const MyReducer = createReducer(
    initState,

    on(UpdateUserActionSuccess, (state, { user }) => {
        const newState = { ...state };

        // do stuff to newState, then

        return {
            ...newState,
            dataState: UserStateEnum.LOADED,
            currentUser: user,
            users: state.users.concat(user)
        };
    }),
```

Remember that state is **immutable**, so cannot be "modified". A reducer returns a brand new state object containing whichever changes you require.